# Pandas Series - How to calculate items weighted score across series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

This is a data series, how do i extract it to obtain the output as below

```
   Bundle        Price

   [A, C, B]      10    
   [A, B, C, D]   20
   [B]            30
```

`Output`

```
    A = 15 ((10+20)/2)
    B = 20 ((10+20+30)/3)
    C=  15 ((10+20)/2)
    D = 20
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `explode`

```
out = df.explode('Bundle').groupby('Bundle').Price.mean()
```